# Website bigger in Chrome than Internet Explorer

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, html, css, dpi

I am viewing this page in Chrome version 55.0.2883.87 m and IE version 11.0.

http://isometricland.net/keyboard/chart-doom-doom-ii-hell-on-earth.php?gam=4&sty=15&lay=1

The page uses a lot of absolutely positioned parts that have dimensions that should be respected by the browser (at least by default). However, Chrome seems to enlarge everything when compared to IE.

I figured it may be because Chrome is using my Windows display DPI settings, and IE is not. But this thread says Chrome *ignores* the Windows DPI settings.

[How to make Google Chrome honor my Windows DPI setting?](https://superuser.com/questions/32855/how-to-make-google-chrome-honor-my-windows-dpi-setting)

What is going on, and is there a way to disable whatever it is Chrome is doing? Thanks!

Comment: KISS: Chrome is set to 100% zoom, right?  (Try Ctrl+0.)

Comment: Yes, it is set to 100%.